# How to deduce group-membership in db2

Tags: database, db2, privileges

(The intro is similar to my previous question, this is not a duplicate)

I'm developing a security product for databases in java. One feature in this product is creating security recommendations based on db-privileges and activity.

In order to do that I need to extract privilege data from db2.
Privileges extracted from DB2's catalog tables have the GTYPE column which determine if the grantee is a user or a group.

In the latter case I also need to know which users are members in that group. But group membership is not defined in DB2, but is based on an external entity (OS usually).

In my case I don't have direct access to the OS of the DB i want to monitor, So the question is: Is there any way to deduce the group-user relationship from db2's catalog tables (or anywhere else)

Thanks

Comment: No there is not. As you say, authentication happens outside DB2, so the DB2 instance does not know or care about what users or groups may exist.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the `AUTH_LIST_AUTHORITIES_FOR_AUTHID` table function, there is another table function, `AUTH_LIST_GROUPS_FOR_AUTHID` that can answer the question.

```
$ db2 "SELECT * FROM TABLE (SYSPROC.AUTH_LIST_GROUPS_FOR_AUTHID('AMY')) AS T"

GROUP
-------------------------...-------------
BUILD
PDXDB2

  2 record(s) selected.
```